# Improving performance of long-running tasks

Tags: performance, task-parallel-library

Currently my software does quite a bit of background work with tasks. One constantly running being a watchdog which does frequent checks for operations that should be executed regularly (like once a day) and also ensures that devices are "plug & play" thus reconnecting in case of faults, connection losses or other situations.

At the customer site the software handles a total of 2 devices, each having 2 sensors (so 4 in total) where each sends about 5Mbit/s of data irregularly (so quite a bit to process in total considering the time). My library is implemented in a way which runs a task that processes incoming data via TCP/IP and pushes that via the `Thread Pool` to another method processing the data set.

Now we realized that sometimes we get data which seems to be old (like 1-3 seconds old). My theory is that since those 4 sensors are read out in tasks which are spawned in my application (which also does a bit of constant background work) the execution of those 4 tasks sometimes starves so much that they cannot read out the data in real-time anymore producing results that seem to be too old.

Now what I would like to know from you is what could I possibly do to improve this situation? I'm not sure what is best-practice for such a scenario but I've come up with the following solutions:

- Optimizing execution by using some "High Priority Task Scheduler" for those sensor-reading tasks
- Finding and/or analyzing and fixing possible hick-ups in the software itself which might cause execution to delay (possibly the first thing to do)
- Move those sensor-reading tasks into own processes ensuring independence of execution (which introduces a new layer of data-passing, forces major refactoring and possibly introduces new bugs and issues)

I know this is quite theoretical and I can't give you much to work on, but just by reading what would your guess be?

Comment: If  it sporadically happends , it's normal, if it frequently happens , we can think of that.

Comment: This isn't theoretical, it's unclear. Your code could be using anything, as all TPL classes use the ThreadPool. Coding problems can't be fixed by using a higher priority. I suspect that your code is *not* using the most appropriate library though - the TPL Dataflow library. It was created as an offshoot of Microsoft's Robotics framework way back when, and allows the creation of pipelines or network of connected processing blocks. Each block runs on its own worker task(s) has its own input/output buffers and ensures ordered input and output. Sounds familiar?

Comment: By default, each block uses a single worker, but you can increase that if needed. Ordering is still preserved.

Comment: `Move those sensor-reading tasks into own processes ensuring independence of execution` no it doesn't, the OS schedules threads, not processes. On the other hand, if the rest of the application allocates too many temporary objects, garbage collection can kick in and freeze everything while it works. You can check GC runs through Windows' Performance monitor or profilers

Comment: Thanks to all. I'll look into the TPL Dataflow library, sounds promising. I actually think that GC and some poor performing implementations are the culprit of it. I don't really think that a modern PC couldn't handle this workload in (approx.) real-time. @Mr.AF it does happen sporadically and that's already too much. So it's not quite normal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single answer.  I will start with your point 2: *Finding and/or analyzing and fixing possible hick-ups in the software*.

You can also make sure the TreadPool is running with enough number of threads, using [SetMinThreads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=netcore-3.1).  I recommend setting the TP to have at least the number of threads for all your sensor reader workers plus at least a couple more for other tasks that may be polled to the threadpool.

If that doesn't help, you should very carefully profile your app using [PerfView](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: Generic answer, not knowing the details about TPL)

There are some things you can do to improve the situation

1. Use profiling to find time-consuming code elements, and improve these places.
2. Understand the situations leading to the delays. Therefore introduce a few lines of code doing a "real-time check" at appropriate places, and place breakpoints there, pausing the whole application, not only the current thread. Then examine how many threads are active, what they are doing (urgent work or uncritical background tasks), whether they are blocking one another, etc.
3. If TPL supports priorities, give a higher priority to real-time tasks.

In addition, I'd recommend that you keep the "real-time check" code even in the production version, log these situations, and decide on a reaction strategy (alert the user, skip some data, whatever might be appropriate). In today's complex desktop-oriented software environments, it's difficult to guarantee real-time processing, so delays will again happen in the future, no matter what you do in the code.